# how to use LWUIT in eclipse for Symbian OS development. how to install LWUIT in eclipse.?

Tags: java-me, symbian

i'm working in eclipse using S60 i want to know how to use LWUIT and eSWT in Symbian OS development?
 what is the difference b/w LWUIT and eSWT.?
 in my view these two are using for GUI. but i need how to work in eclipse do not any structs are using these two.
   please help me.
Than you.